# How to get fortigate device access using sl api

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to get list of fortigate devices from a specific account using nodejs . I have added a function that uses methods and objects available in the SL api but getting below error:

```
{ error: 'Function ("GetNetworkVlanFirewall") is not a valid method for this service.',
```

The API method I'm calling is `GetNetworkVlanFirewall` under service `Network_Vlan`

This is the .path I am using:

`.path('Network_Vlan','GetNetworkVlanFirewall')`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the method name is wrong and the vlan identifier is missing too. Try using the below example:

```
.path('Network_Vlan',vlanId,'getNetworkVlanFirewall')
```

Reference:

https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Vlan/getNetworkVlanFirewall/

If you want to know the list of Multi-Vlan-Firewalls in the account you can use the following rest api call:

Method: GET

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkGateways?objectMask=mask[id,name,networkFirewall[id,customerManagedFlag,datacenter.name],publicIpAddress.ipAddress,publicVlan[id,primaryRouter.hostname],privateIpAddress.ipAddress,insideVlans[id],memberCount,status.keyName]
```

To know just the single vlan-firewalls list use the below example:

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkVlans?objectMask=mask[networkVlanFirewall[billingItem[id,categoryCode,item],firewallType]]
```

To get the specific information for a network vlan firewall use the following example:

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Vlan_Firewall/[firewallId]/getObject?objectMask=mask[billingItem,customerManagedFlag,fullyQualifiedDomainName,managementCredentials,networkVlan[id,firewallInterfaces,primaryRouter[hostname,id],vlanNumber],primaryIpAddress, bypassRequestStatus]
```

Comment: getNetworkGateways gives vyattas list so that will not work here. May be getNetworkVlans gives information of fortigates

Comment: @Ojeda I can get fortigate list now with method getNetworkVlans  . How I can get hardware ids of those firewalls?

Comment: The fortigate device you will find for Multi-vlan and single-vlan that's why I sent you both option. With the method getNetworkGateways and using a "mask" with the "networkFirewall" relational property you will get the multi-vlan-firewalls, like fortigate devices which were added to a specific router, this method and service use the portal control.

Comment: You can see more information about multi-vlan here: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/infrastructure/fortigate-10g/getting-started.html#getting-started, https://console.bluemix.net/docs/infrastructure/fortigate-10g/viewing-firewalls.html#view-list-of-firewalls, https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/fr/node/1608

Comment: Try using the following rest api: https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkVlans?objectMask=mask[hardware[id,networkVlans[id,networkVlanFirewall[id,firewallType,billingItem[id,item[description]]]]]]&objectFilter={"networkVlans":{"hardware":{"networkVlans":{"networkVlanFirewall":{"billingItem":{"item":{"description":{"operation":"*=fortigate"}}}}}}}}